# C++ function not found during compilation

Tags: c++, hash

For a homework assignment: I'm supposed to create randomized alphabetial keys, print them to a file, and then hash each of them into a hash table using the function "goodHash", found in my below code.

When I try to run the below code, it says my "goodHash" "identifier isn't found". What's wrong with my code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "math.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

// "makeKey" function to create an alphabetical key 
// based on 8 randomized numbers 0 - 25.
string makeKey() {
    int k;
    string key = "";
    for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
        int keyNumber = (rand() % 25);
        if (keyNumber == 0)
            key.append("A");
        if (keyNumber == 1)
            key.append("B");
        if (keyNumber == 2)
            key.append("C");
        if (keyNumber == 3)
            key.append("D");
        if (keyNumber == 4)
            key.append("E");
        if (keyNumber == 5)
            key.append("F");
        if (keyNumber == 6)
            key.append("G");
        if (keyNumber == 7)
            key.append("H");
        if (keyNumber == 8)
            key.append("I");
        if (keyNumber == 9)
            key.append("J");
        if (keyNumber == 10)
            key.append("K");
        if (keyNumber == 11)
            key.append("L");
        if (keyNumber == 12)
            key.append("M");
        if (keyNumber == 13)
            key.append("N");
        if (keyNumber == 14)
            key.append("O");
        if (keyNumber == 15)
            key.append("P");
        if (keyNumber == 16)
            key.append("Q");
        if (keyNumber == 17)
            key.append("R");
        if (keyNumber == 18)
            key.append("S");
        if (keyNumber == 19)
            key.append("T");
        if (keyNumber == 20)
            key.append("U");
        if (keyNumber == 21)
            key.append("V");
        if (keyNumber == 22)
            key.append("W");
        if (keyNumber == 23)
            key.append("X");
        if (keyNumber == 24)
            key.append("Y");
        if (keyNumber == 25)
            key.append("Z");
    }
    return key;
}

// "makeFile" function to produce the desired text file.
// Note this only works as intended if you include the ".txt" extension,
// and that a file of the same name doesn't already exist.
void makeFile(string fileName, int n) {
    ofstream ourFile;
    ourFile.open(fileName);
    int k; // For use in below loop to compare with n.
    int l; // For use in the loop inside the below loop.
    string keyToPassTogoodHash = "";
    for (k = 1; k <= n; k++) {
        for (l = 0; l < 8; l++) {    // For-loop to write to the file ONE key
        ourFile << makeKey()[l];
        keyToPassTogoodHash += (makeKey()[l]);
        }
        ourFile << "  " << k << "\n";// Writes two spaces and the data value
        goodHash(keyToPassTogoodHash); // I think this has to do with the problem
        makeKey(); // Call again to make a new key.
    }
}

// Primary function to create our desired file!
void mainFunction(string fileName, int n) {
    makeKey();
    makeFile(fileName, n);
}

// Hash Table for Part 2
struct Node {
    int key;
    string value;
    Node* next;
}; 
const int hashTableSize = 10;
Node* hashTable[hashTableSize];

// "goodHash" function for Part 2
void goodHash(string key) {
    int x = 0;
    int y;
    int keyConvertedToNumber = 0;
    // For-loop to produce a numeric value based on the alphabetic key,
    // which is then hashed into hashTable using the hash function
    // declared below the loop (hashFunction).
    for (y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
        if (key[y] == 'A' || 'B' || 'C')
            x = 0;
        if (key[y] == 'D' || 'E' || 'F')
            x = 1;
        if (key[y] == 'G' || 'H' || 'I')
            x = 2;
        if (key[y] == 'J' || 'K' || 'L')
            x = 3;
        if (key[y] == 'M' || 'N' || 'O')
            x = 4;
        if (key[y] == 'P' || 'Q' || 'R')
            x = 5;
        if (key[y] == 'S' || 'T')
            x = 6;
        if (key[y] == 'U' || 'V')
            x = 7;
        if (key[y] == 'W' || 'X')
            x = 8;
        if (key[y] == 'Y' || 'Z')
            x = 9;
        keyConvertedToNumber = x + keyConvertedToNumber; 
    }
    int hashFunction = keyConvertedToNumber % hashTableSize;
    Node *temp;
    temp = new Node;
    temp->value = key;
    temp->next = hashTable[hashFunction];
    hashTable[hashFunction] = temp;
}

// First two lines are for Part 1, to call the functions key to Part 1.
int main() {
    srand ( time(NULL) );            // To make sure our randomization works.
    mainFunction("sandwich.txt", 5); // To test program
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I realize my code is cumbersome in some sections, but I'm a noob at C++ and don't know much to do it better.

I'm guessing another way I could do it is to AFTER writing the alphabetical keys to the file, read them from the file and hash each key as I do that, but I wouldn't know how to go about coding that.

Comment: One tip that works for ASCII character sets at least: `if (keyNumber >= 0 && keyNumber <= 25) key.append('A' + keyNumber);`.  Also, you might consider changing your question title to something like "function not found during compilation" as this question has nothing to do with hashing etc.

Comment: "Holy if statement batman!" Perhaps you are noob at C++, but i guess by now you should already know `switch` statement, right?

Comment: Your comparisons are incorrect, you must specify `if ((key[y] == 'U') || (key[y] == 'V'))`.

Comment: Your hash function doesn't handle lower case:  use a key of "hello".

Comment: Since you said that you’re a beginner in C++ and that some parts of your code are cumbersome, why don’t you head over to [codereview.StackExchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get a detailed critique of this code? Unfortunately, Stack Overflow isn’t the right place for this but on Code Review we’d be more than happy to do just that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ expected everything to be declared in order, so that nothing's used before it's declared.
If you need to refer to a function higher in the file than where it's defined, you need to have a function prototype near the top of the file that declares the function. (Writing prototypes for *all* functions is a standard practice as a result of this.)

Near the top of the file (after the `#include`s) simply add

```
void goodHash(string key);
```

---

Definitions

Function declaration: something that declares the name of the function and the types the function takes.

Function definition: something that specifies the actual code of the function.

Comment: I just moved the whole goodHash function to the top, and it seems to be working. That should be fine, right? Or if I just put `void goodHash(string key)` on the top and leave everything else, it should produce the same result, correct?

Comment: Yes, that will work, but you should be aware of the conventions behind function prototypes.

Comment: You need a semicolon in a forward declaration: `void goodHash(string key);`.

Comment: Whooops, typo. Yeah, I just put in that line at the top. So I guess from now on, for all my functions I should do this just to be on the safe side?

Comment: "(Writing prototypes for all functions is a standard practice as a result of this.)" - for situations like this where the function's only used in the same translation unit, prototypes are one of two options, the other being to define the functions before they're used - there's no preferred standard practice across the C++ community in this regard, purely down to personal taste and per-project/company coding standards if any.  IMHO, forward declarations make it easier to accidentally introduce unnecessary cyclic dependencies, and I tend to program "bottom up" within each .cpp/.cc/.c++ file.

Answer (score 3):

if you insert

```
void goodHash(string key);
```

in the line under "using namespace..." it will work

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you have to forward declare `goodHash` or define `goodHash` before `makeFile` if you want to use `goodHash` in `makeFile`.  Otherwise, when the compile is in `makeFile`, it sees the token `goodHash` and hasn't found out what it means, which is why you are getting the compile-time error.

**EDIT**:  [Here is a good resource on forward declarations](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/17-forward-declarations/)

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the function prototype just add this in the top:

```
void goodHash(string key);
```

and btw your makeKey() is too long
you can try this instead:

```
string makeKey() {
    int k;
    string key = "";
    for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
        int keyNumber = (rand() % 25);
        char app[2];
        app[0] = keyNumber + 'A';
        app[1] = 0;
        key.append(app);
        }
    return key;
}
```